# contain the result of Filter function in one cell Excel

Tags: excel, filter

am trying to use the filter function in excel.
The filter function provides the result correctly, but unfortunately if there is more than one result, then there is a spill over to the adjacent cells

Is there any way we contain the result of the filter function in one cell?

Consider the function below, the filter functions result is 4 separate values, I am trying to have all the values in one cell, is that possible?
eg: value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4

[image: Consider the function below, the filter functions result is 4 separate values, I am trying to have all the values in one cell, is that possible?]

This is the formula that i am using
`=FILTER($I$2:$I$595,M10=$E$2:$E$595)`

Comment: Wrap your `FILTER` function in `TEXTJOIN`.

Comment: @JosWoolley ur answer is even better. is there a way we can give "alt - enter" as the delimiter?

Comment: Use `CHAR(10)` as the delimiter.

Comment: Took me a second to realize that your cells need to be formatted to "wrap text" in order to get the desired result. Just adding for future answer seekers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple,

All you have to do is use the filter function along with the concat function

`Concat(filter ())`

Answer (score 1):

you can use =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(range,condition1))
this will definitely help you.